# C++ class member hiding rules: Design question

Tags: c++, interface

I've got a base class, `Message`, that dictates policy. I've also got derivations of that class for specific message instances.

Consider this simplified example:

```
template< ::size_t MessageSize >
struct Message {
    enum { size = MessageSize };
    Bits< ChunkSize > bits_[size / ChunkSize];
    // Defines behavior for the Message types
};

template< ::size_t MessageSize >
struct SmallMessage : public Message< MessageSize > {
    Bits< MessageSize > bits_;
};

// other derivations of Message...

template< class MessageType, ::size_t MessageSize >
struct MakeMessage {
    typedef typename IfElseType<
            MessageSize < ChunkSize,
            SmallMessage< MessageSize >,
            Message< MessageSize >
        >::type type;
};
```

If `ChunkSize` is 32 and I generate the following:

```
MakeMessage< FooMessage, 16 >
```

The `Message< 16 >` will result in a `Bits< 32 > bits_[0];` and `SmallMessage< 16 >` will contain `Bits< 16 > bits_` which, as I understand it, will shadow the original, zero-sized member.

There are a couple of ways I know to handle this:

1. Declare a name other than `bits_` and provide an overridden interface to that
2. Modify `SmallMessage` to hide all methods of `Message` that deal with `bits_` with local implementations
3. Make the methods in `Message` virtual

My question is whether there is a benefit to either approach or if there is a better way to provide an interface to various sized memory containers as explained above.

Ultimately, I'd like to have something along the lines of:

```
typedef MakeMessage< FooMessage, 16 >::type message_type;
// ...
message_type message;
message.doSomethingToBits ();
```

Work the same regardless of what container is actually being used.

Comment: few doubts: What's FooMessage (is it Message or SmallMessage) ? When the SmallMessage is used, do you want to hide everything inside Message ?

Comment: `FooMessage` is just a placeholder in the above. In practice it will look something like: `typedef MakeMessage< SomeObject, sizeof (SomeObject) >`
When `SmallMessage` is used I'd ideally like to have access to all of `Message` but be able to have a different implementation of the `bits_` member variable. I don't think that is directly possible, however.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as best as I can forge through this mass of `template` and `typename`, you're trying to use inheritance for composition, which is considered the wrong way to do it. `SmallMessage` here is **not** a type of `Message`, because as you note it doesn't support dealing with the `bits_` array in the same manner.

I think the right way to do this would be to have `Message` as an abstract base class (important: *no* `bits_` of any kind, probably lots of pure virtual functions), and then `SmallMessage` and `BigMessage` as implementations. Also, since you're using templates for everything anyway, the types are worked out at compile time, and there might not actually be a reason to have `Message` at all. As long as `SmallMessage` and `BigMessage` have the same signature, you can use `message_type` as you describe even if they don't have a common base class. The only reason you would need the base class `Message` is if you want to talk about messages more generally, using late binding. Although having the base class will also statically enforce that the signatures match right in the declaration, rather than giving strange errors... sometimes... in distant parts of the code because you misdeclared a method in one of the classes (but not the other).

It's a safe bet you also want the `BigMessage::bits_` to be `[(size-1) / ChunkSize + 1]`, which is just the ceiling rather than the floor. This way you actually have enough `Bits`es to fit all your bits.